# How to support multipart/form-data and application/json by a same method spring boot Rest

Tags: spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I have a POST method that needs to support both multipart/form-data and application/json.

i.e. consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }

When I'm supporting Multipart request, I need a multipart file and a multipart json which can be obtained by declaring as below:

Line 1-> `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("jsonString") InputJsonVO inputJsonVO`

Similarly when supporting an application/json, I need to accept the whole body as a Json content:

Line 2 -> `@RequestBody InputJsonVO inputJsonVO`

It works fine when we have either line 1 or line 2, but not both in the same method as parameters.

```
`@PostMapping(path = "/multipart", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public String getMessage(@RequestPart(required=false, name="file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart(required=false, name="jsonString") InputJsonVO inputJsonVO,
            @RequestBody(required=false) InputJsonVO inputJsonVO2
            )`
```

With this method declaration if I send a POST request:

```
POST /multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
content-type: application/json
Content-Length: 335

<A Valid Json>
```

This works fine.

But when I sent a POST request as below from postman, it doesn't work:

```
POST /multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 650
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/C:/Users/sdamarla/Downloads/J867FE94.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonString"
Content-Type: application/json

<A valid Json>

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

Gives below error:

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------335202067624768397899751' not supported]
```

Note: multipart request is working fine when removing the @RequestBody and the corresponding parameter.

Please let me know if this is a valid use case and if so where am I failing.

Answer (score 0):

Just define two different methods, one for each representation:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/multipart", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getMessage(@RequestBody InputJsonVO inputJsonVO) {
    getMessage(null, inputJsonVO);
}

@PostMapping(path = "/multipart", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String getMessage(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, @RequestPart InputJsonVO inputJsonVO) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: The logic would be pretty much similar on both methods as you can see we are using same Java class to hold json content.. only the multipart value will be additional file that is optional.. so the idea of having 2 methods may not be a best possible solution..moreever if the @Consumes method allows multiple media types on a single method, there should be a way to make use of it efficiently right?

Comment: Well, you don't have to duplicate the logic, just call the one method from the other… see my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah.. creating 2 separate methods is an option I tried earlier and kept as a backup option in case this doesn't work out..but it would really help me if this is possible in a single method

Comment: In this specific case there's really no point in having this in one method because the method parameters differ. IMHO having only a single method with two parameters `inputJsonVO` and `inputJsonVO2` would definitely be much more ugly :)